# VBScript \ Active Directory Searched by displayname and received 2 of the same

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

I have my script to search by displayname and return the userid, which works fine.

but when I encounter a displayname that has 2 entries in AD i.e.

1. pavle stojanovic - he is from company 1
2. pavle stojanovic - he is from company 2

the userid doesnt get displayed because the script doesnt know what to do ?

how do i over come this ? if I get a return of 2 or more I'd like to say in the output hey i found the same name twice etc.. here are the userids and companies for both.

If you want to see the script its below...

```
 strFile = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.ScriptFullName) & "\users.xls"

 Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)
 objWorkbook.Activate
 objExcel.Visible = False


 intRow = 2 ' starts reading file at line 2


' this part runs a loop through the excel file reading each userid and getting data requested.
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""

 ExcelRow = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1)
 Call GetOU ' calling sub to search
 intRow = intRow + 1

Loop



' This section just formats the excel file to widen the columns
' --------------------------------------------------------------

 Set objRange = objExcel.Range("A1")
 objRange.Activate
 Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
 objRange.AutoFit()

 Set objRange = objExcel.Range("B1")
 objRange.Activate
 Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
 objRange.AutoFit()

 Set objRange = objExcel.Range("C1")
 objRange.Activate
 Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
 objRange.AutoFit()

 Set objRange = objExcel.Range("D1")
 objRange.Activate
 Set objRange = objExcel.ActiveCell.EntireColumn
 objRange.AutoFit()

 objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
 objExcel.Quit




' Sub to get Details for user 
' ----------------------------

Sub GetOU

 On Error Resume Next

 Set objRootDSE                       = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
 strDomain                            = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
 Set objConnection                    = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 objConnection.Provider               = "ADsDSOObject"
 objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCommand                       = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set objCommand.ActiveConnection      = objConnection
 objCommand.Properties("Size Limit")  = 100000
 objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2
 objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT distinguishedName FROM 'LDAP://" & _ 
 strDomain & _
 "' WHERE objectCategory='User' AND DisplayName = '" & _
 ExcelRow & "'"
 Set objRecordSet                     = objCommand.Execute


 If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then

  strDN = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value


' ###########################################################
' ###########################################################

' This is where the script does 'its thing' ... 
' gets what you want.
' ------------------------------------------------


 Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://" & strDN)


 objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = UCASE(MyUser.SamAccountName)



' ###########################################################
' ###########################################################



 Else

  Wscript.Echo "User Not Found: " & ExcelRow

 End If

 Err.Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If multiple accounts are found, the Record Set will have multiple records and you'll need to loop through it. Your code currently only gets the first item in the Record Set.

Change `If Not objRecordSet.EOF Then` to `Do While Not objRecordSet.EOF`
Then

```
strDN = objRecordSet.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
' ###########################################################
' ###########################################################
Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://" & strDN)
```

When inserting the users into the spreadsheet, you'll want to control the placement of the cell dynamically so the same cell isn't written over at each loop.

```
objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = UCASE(MyUser.SamAccountName)
```

At the end of processing this user, you'll use this to move to the next object (user) in the Record Set

```
objRecordSet.MoveNext
```

Then instead of `End If`, you'll use `Loop`

EDIT:

Also, instead of connecting to the object using `Set MyUser = GetObject(etc)`, could you just use `"SELECT sAMAccountName FROM...` in your query then `strsAMAccountName = objRecordSet.Fields("sAMAccountName")` to save some memory/time?

Edit2:
I am doing this in my script.

```
If objRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then  
    'Things to do if not found
    Exit Sub 'Then exit before entering loop
End If
```

Also, if the user isn't found then `objRecordSet.EOF` will equal `True`.

Comment: thanks mate, i can try that BUT how will i get a 'else' statement incase the 'user' doesnt exist if i loop it ?